# A Single Particle in an Expanding Universe

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, cosmology

If we have a universe that is completely empty, such as the Milne model, we still have an expansion of the scale factor. Likewise, a matter only universe leads to a different, but still expanding scale factor.

If we have a universe, empty but for one particle (does that correspond more closely to the EdS or Milne case?), how does the expansion of the scale factor effect that particle's wave function?

Is the wavefunction spread out by the expansion, or left untouched?

If the scale factor can expand faster than the speed of light, can the wave function be spread out faster than the speed of light?

I think the answer should be no, since the wavefunction represents a probability of finding the particle in a given place, and the probability of finding the particle at a distance greater than that which light could have travelled in that time seems not to make sense.

Comment: I would also think that c should be used to define a volume out of which the wf should vanish. Though I have hard time to see how/why the wf expand upon expansion if not in a very very big rip scenario.

Comment: The scale factor doesn’t “expand”, space “expands”. The rate of expansion is not s speed, so it makes no sense to talk about space, or anything else, expanding faster than the speed of light.